# RC-circuit with one input terminal and many outputs with different integration time

Tags: capacitor, resistors, circuit-design, integrator

What is the simplest way to create an RC-integrator with one input terminal and several output terminals which differ their times of integration (see schematics below).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXhDSE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

NOTE: It is intended to plug-in only one output at a time.

I think the following circuit would work. But think that calculation for three and more output terminals would be messy. Though I don't know if any desired times of integration could be obtained by this schematics.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBk67J.png)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Buffer the input signal with a unity-gain opamp follower.  Then follow that by different pairs of resistors in series, followed by capacitors to ground:

[image]

Comment: Seems really simple but I don't see any resistors in series here. Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: @LRDPRDX R1 R2 and R3 are in series with the OUT1 OUT2 and OUT3 respectively.

Comment: What would happen without an amp. I undersrand more or less the using of a buffer. In my case the input signal is from a photomultiplier tube which is not greater than a couple of volts. Integrated signal then should go to an oscilloscope with input impedance of 50Ω or 1MΩ.

Comment: @LPD: If you know your source signal is low enough impedance, you can leave off the buffer.  If you don't know how the impedance, or don't know how to decide when its low enough, don't leave off the buffer.  Also, the R1-Rn resistors need to be "small" compared to whatever impedance you connect to the OUTn outputs, else the low pass filter rolloff frequency will be effected.  Perhaps you need to put buffers on the OUTn lines too.